# Angular8 - error TS2304: Cannot find name

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular8

I'm using angular2-query-builder from 
[www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-query-builder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-query-builder)

When trying to include bootstrap style in the .ts file

```
classNames: QueryBuilderClassNames = {
        removeIcon: 'fa fa-minus',
        addIcon: 'fa fa-plus',
        arrowIcon: 'fa fa-chevron-right px-2',
        button: 'btn',
        buttonGroup: 'btn-group',
        rightAlign: 'order-12 ml-auto',
        switchRow: 'd-flex px-2',
        switchGroup: 'd-flex align-items-center',
        switchRadio: 'custom-control-input',
        switchLabel: 'custom-control-label',
        switchControl: 'custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline',
        row: 'row p-2 m-1',
        rule: 'border',
        ruleSet: 'border',
        invalidRuleSet: 'alert alert-danger',
        emptyWarning: 'text-danger mx-auto',
        operatorControl: 'form-control',
        operatorControlSize: 'col-auto pr-0',
        fieldControl: 'form-control',
        fieldControlSize: 'col-auto pr-0',
        entityControl: 'form-control',
        entityControlSize: 'col-auto pr-0',
        inputControl: 'form-control',
        inputControlSize: 'col-auto'
      }
```

i'm getting below error

```
ERROR in src/app/CompSqlBuilder/sqlBuilder.component.ts(44,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'QueryBuilderClassNames'.
```

I have already included bootstrap 4 in the project. please advice what i have to import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the below import fixed it

```
import { QueryBuilderConfig, QueryBuilderClassNames } from "angular2-query-builder";
```